# plsql return a record set suitable for FOR statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to return by a function a suitable record set for "FOR" statement

I have code like:

```
FOR cur in (SELECT %random_columns% FROM only_this_table where 1=1 and %random_fileter%) LOOP
    %some actions with cur% 
END LOOP;
```

and I need to wrap this select into a function call to do some additional staff with it before execute. The desired look of the code is like:

```
FOR cur in get_rows( %random_columns%, %random_fileter%) LOOP
    %some actions with cur%
END LOOP;
```

%some actions with cur% are some additional statements that may differ for each loop

Comment: You can use cursors based on dynamic SQL.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish something like this using [table functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm). Best of luck.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff If a record has "random" fields, how the `some_actions_on()` subprogram can use the record ? Doesn't `get_rows()` and `some_actions_on()` have to agree the record type (i.e. the record fields) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it for a record only like in [How to return a record from an existing table from an Oracle PL/SQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336743/how-to-return-a-record-from-an-existing-table-from-an-oracle-pl-sql-function) , then you can do it for an array of those.